# Complete references in between the document

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

When we do

```
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{References.bib}
```

We get all the references at the end of the document, with some kind of reference/id in the document.

What I need is the complete reference in the document itself (not at the end) and then to be able to write what I want below this reference. For example;

```
Chaminade, T., Hodgins, J., & Kawato, M. (2007). "Anthropomorphism influences perception of computer-animated characters' actions." Social Cognitive and Affective Neuroscience 2(3): 206-216
     - Some text..........
     - Some more text.......

Cowley, S. J., Kanda, T. (2005). "Friendly machines: interaction-oriented robots today and tomorrow." Alternation 12(1a): 79-106.
     - Some text.....
     - Some more text....
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend using biblatex's `\fullcite` command, which inserts the bibliography entry into your document wherever you like. E.g.,

```
\fullcite{knuth1990}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text \item some more text
\end{itemize}
```